# "TypeError: can't convert undefined to object" only after vite build, before, with vide dev, everything works perfectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, vite

I'm using Vite combined with React and Typescript.
When I run `vite dev` the live version of the website runs perfectly, not even errors on the console.

When I run `vite build` and then `vite preview` all I get to see is a white page and the
`TypeError: can't convert undefined to object`
error in the console.

I cannot trace the problem in my code because the error happens after the build/minimization, but just to be sure, I added safety checks in the instances where I call `Object.keys()`.

This is the segment of the code where the error starts:

```js
Object.keys(pd).forEach(function (e) {
  if (pd[e] === 0)
    Xd.prototype["on" + e] = function () {
      this.scope.emit(e);
    };
  else if (pd[e] === 1)
    Xd.prototype["on" + e] = function (t) {
      this.scope.emit(e, t);
    };
});
```

Edit:

I was checking the minimized code and right before the long block of code where the bug is, I saw a MuiTouchRipple. I'm using the MaterialUI library, is it possible that the library is causing this problem?
I tried to update from version 5.4.2 to 5.6.3, but after the build it still crashes.

[image]

Comment: There's not enough context to reproduce the problem. Can you show the code that causes the problem?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, i don't know where the code that causes the problem is.
My code runs smoothly, and both eslint and typescript report no errors. The problem appears only after minimization and as you can see in the screenshot I attached, it doesn't point to a specific file, but to the minimized bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

Posting the debug steps for the newbies like me.

## Debug

### 1. Disable minimization

This allows you to see the original code, it's still in a bundled form, so you still cannot identify the exact file where the problem is, but at least you know something more. (in my specific case, since I'm using vite I had to change a variable in the config file, see https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-minify).

### 2. Change typescript compiler options

In my case the target and module were set to ESNext, trying to change it to ES6 or to commonjs helped to have a better searchable code.
(see https://www.tsmean.com/articles/learn-typescript/typescript-module-compiler-option/)

### 3. Search the code that causes the error

When I tried to search the code in vscode it did not appear. That's a good sign, at least my code was not causing the problem!

But at the same time: what now?

The solution I found is to either disable vscode excluded folders from the search (by default vscode does not search in `node_modules`), or to use `grep -r` in the project folder.
I found the latter to be faster and more efficient.

## Solution

In my specific case the problem was an old library that hasn't been updated in years (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser). Once I removed it everything started working.

Comment: same package was giving me error, found a replacement html-react-parse, changed it and it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, and for me this was caused by `"target": "es5"` in tsconfig.json.

After changing to `esnext`, problem is gone.

https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#es5

Comment: Thank you @Berenluth and @partizan! Your answers brought me onto the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me it was the `build.lib.formats` setting in `vite.config.ts`, that I needed to remove.